# parameter is declared but its value is never read... why not

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

To send an email, I have a controller method as such:

```
const send = function (subject, template, to, options) {
// VSC says about "subject": is declared but its value is never read. 
// VSC does not say this for the other three parameters.
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile(template, "utf8", function (err, templateContent) {
            if (err) {
                return resolve(false);
            }

            var subject = subject;
            console.log(subject);
            // this is where I do read "subject" but it returns 'undefined'
            // (even though I am passing the function a value for the parameter)

            ... etc
```

What am I doing wrong? In my mind, I have declared a parameter `subject` and I use later on in the controller method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> var subject = subject;
> ```

`var subject` creates a new variable, named `subject` in the scope of the callback function passed to `readFile`.

This [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the `subject` variable created as a parameter name for the function assigned to `send`.

`var subject = subject;` therefore copies the value of the local `subject` (which is `undefined` at the time) to `subject` (which does nothing).

**Give your variables different names** even if they do similar things.

I recommend the use of a linter which can enforce a rule like [no-shadow](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow) (you seem to be using one already — VS Code won't generate the error message, only report it from a tool which does — so make sure you turn that rule on for that tool).

Answer (score 1):

`var` inside the function will be hoisted to the top so at runtime it is:

```
fs.readFile(template, "utf8", function (err, templateContent) {
  var subject;
  // ...
  subject = subject; //undefined
});
```

Just use another name for your nested subject like `_subject` and avoid shadowing variable names in general.